# Eslint arrow-body-style error in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lint, eslint

Using Airbnb's eslint rules, I'm getting the following error in my react code but I'm not sure what's the error.

```
const Facebook = ({ appId, url }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.facebook}>
      <FacebookProvider appID={appId}>
        <EmbeddedPost href={url} width="auto" />
      </FacebookProvider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Getting an error at the beginning of line 1 `{` bracket.

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)

Tried wrapping the curly brackets with parenthesis brackets but in turn, another error appear around line 3 of `<div>`.

> Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Are you wanting to create a function (`Facebook`) that takes one object argument (with properties `appId` and `url`) or two arguments, `appId` and `url`?

Comment: See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5498

Comment: You can use `eslint --fix` to fix it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the curly braces and the return as per the [issue linked](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5498#issuecomment-247049075) in the comment for your question:

```
const Facebook = ({ appId, url }) => 
    <div className={styles.facebook}>
        <FacebookProvider appID={appId}>
            <EmbeddedPost href={url} width="auto" />
        </FacebookProvider>
    </div>
```

Comment: Following that comment you linked, it said to nuke the return and braces around it.

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes.