# How to fix a block statement from a eslint arrow body error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linter

I have the following:

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <MyLayout {...props}>
      ...
```

I need to pass props to MyLayout, problem is eslint doesn't like this and is rejecting the code w:

**unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body**

How can I get the func to pass props and comply with eslint?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eslint arrow-body-style error in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217761/eslint-arrow-body-style-error-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the props but around arrow body when you only have return inside it, you dont need to have curly brackets or return.

This will work.

```js
const MyPage = (props) => <div>
<MyLayout {...props}>
.... 
</MyLayout>
<MyComponent />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have content inside the <MyLayout tag... so that's resulting in the following error: `Prevent missing parentheses around multiline JSX (react/jsx-wrap-multilines)
`

Comment: <MyLayout {...props}> your content... </MyLayout> this will work, if you have content inside you need opening and closing brackets. Also if you have multiple lines, then enclose in a div.

Comment: not sure what to say, it's still erroring in the editor w "missing parentheses around multiline JSX"

Comment: @AnnaSm that error is because you are using multiple adjacent tags, enclose in divs. Let me update my answer to make it morr clear.

Comment: sorry same message about missing parentheses around multiline JSX

Comment: @AnnaSm can you update your question with the exact code, Instead of (...) .