# ES6: unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I've seen a few questions regarding this, but I can't make any sense out of it.

## The Problem:

```
const Component = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      // lots of components, .jsx logic, inline ifs, styles etc.
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

For the code above ESLinter (airbnb) returns:

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned
> value immediately after the `=>`.eslint(arrow-body-style)

I want to fix it, not ignore it.

## 1. Fix #1 (not working):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217761/eslint-arrow-body-style-error-in-react-js) previously, but not helpful.

```
const Component = ({ data }) =>
  <Wrapper>
    (...)
  </Wrapper>
```

> Missing parentheses around multilines JSX
> eslint(react/jsx-wrap-multilines)

I'm glad, because it looks awful.

## 2. Solution #2 (not working):

```
const Component = ({ data }) => {
  <Wrapper>
    (...)
  </Wrapper>
}
```

ESLint is happy (although it forces me to insert `;` after `</Wrapper>` and it looks bad. Anyway no matter what my app becomes broken like this:

```
Error: Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

(1) use implicit return (no `{`s)

(2) surround the returned JSX with parentheses to satisfy `jsx-wrap-multilines`:

```
const Component = ({ data }) => (
  <Wrapper>
    // lots of components, .jsx logic, inline ifs, styles etc.
  </Wrapper>
);
```